# SpringFox, Spring Data Rest with JpaRepository - Swagger doesn't recognize Rest repositories with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger, springfox

I'm having a trouble with Springfox swagger 2 for my API documentation. It couldn't recognize my rest repositories (JpaRepository/PagingAndSortingRepository).

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.aegon.dop.model.Book;

public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

Even I tried adding swagger annotations like below, but no luck

```
@Api(tags = "books")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "books", path = "books")
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, String> {
    @ApiOperation("Find all books by book name")
    Dopadviseur findByBookName(@Param("bookName") @RequestParam @ApiParam(value = "bookName") String bookName);
}
```

Whereas, HAL browser could identify my rest repositories. Can someone help me with this.
Here are my pom dependencies,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Demo</name>
    <description>Demo application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.0.1</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <spring-fox-version>2.9.2</spring-fox-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-fox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-fox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-fox-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Soap Webservices -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>           
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>       
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Here is my boot class,

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.configuration.SpringDataRestConfiguration;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@Import({ SpringDataRestConfiguration.class })
public class DopApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DopApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I add `@Import({ SpringDataRestConfiguration.class })` , I get the following error on application start up

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.getRepositoryInformationFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;
    at springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.EntityServicesProvider.requestHandlers(EntityServicesProvider.java:81) ~[springfox-data-rest-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper$2.apply(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:138) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper$2.apply(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:135) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:null]
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.transform(Iterators.java:750) ~[guava-20.0.jar:na]
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I suspect that it is required the version 3.0.0 of SpringFox that unfortunately is not yet released.

Comment: No, I couldn't find any solution for this yet.

Answer (score 1):

### Intro

I think you need to include the following in your code:

`@Import({springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.configuration.SpringDataRestConfiguration.class})`

Have a look at the following thread that discusses your problem:

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/699#issuecomment-270052170

### Full Proposed Answer from Github:

`@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@Import({springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.configuration.SpringDataRestConfiguration.class})
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {`

### Update

I think you should upgrade to:

Spring Fox 2.9.0 : https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2372
They mention a problem very similar to yours that is solved by that release.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2272

Comment: Hi Menelaos, thanks for your response. I tried this solution as well. Now I'm getting this error at application start up. `ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.getRepositoryInformationFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;`

Comment: @Nagarjuna Adapa try upgrading to 2.9.0 of springfox. Change the definition in your pom.xml

Comment: I'm using springfox 2.9.2, even then I had the same issue. I have edited my question with pom and main class.

Comment: @Nagarjuna Adapa can you provide the whole pom.xml with all your dependencies? I will try making a project and testing it.

Comment: Did anyone get to the bottom of this issue?  Have the exact same issue/configuration as [here][1] but can’t seem to get Swagger UI (latest version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT) to display the generated endpoints by Spring Data REST.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58751615/sping-data-rest-endpoints-not-generating-in-swagger-ui